# Display posts from deep child categories in Archive

Tags: wordpress

As far as I understand, WordPress for archive page has a default category nesting limit. In my case, the nesting consists of 3 or 4 categories. And if i go to the very top category in the hierarchy, I would like to display posts for all children's categories

Is it possible to change the nesting level of archives?

I also tried custom query, but also without results.

```
    $args = [
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => $postType,
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $currentCategoryId,
                'include_children' => true,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ],
        ],
    ];
```